# How can I evaluate the definite integrals with limits?

Tags: analysis

How can I evaluate the following limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{4}\right)^n\sin(nx)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^2+x+1}{4} \leq \frac{3}{4}$ on the given interval, and $\sin(nx)$ is bounded, so the integrand converges uniformly to zero and so the limit is zero.